# Woocommerce get 401 when using localhost base_url, but success when using public ip

Tags: php, laravel, woocommerce, guzzle, woocommerce-rest-api

I have wordpress with woocommerce for REST API, the wordpress is running on docker.
For http client i'm using Guzzle6 with Oauth libs in Laravel app to do the Request. The laravel app is run behind nginx
When i set the base_url to localhost:port i got `401` response

```
{
    "code":"woocommerce_rest_authentication_error",
    "message":"Invalid signature - provided signature does not match.
}
```

When i set the base_url to my `public ip` it success.
When i develop on my local machine it success using localhost as base_url Why this happend ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a same issue with WooCommerce trying to send a simple `GET` request with postman on localhost. I fixed it by setting `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` to my local ip address, or go to `Admin Panel > Settings > General` and replace `localhost` with your ip-address for `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` as explained here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180207/how-to-make-other-computer-in-local-network-see-my-theme

Hope this helps.